# Best practice for java web services and remote exception

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing a web service. So I have:

```
public interface MyService extends Remote
{
  public void service1();
}

public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService
{
  public void service1() { /* do something that sometimes throws an exception */ }
}
```

I was reading about `RemoteException`. Should I wrap all the code in `service1()` in a `try..catch` that wraps any exception in a `RemoteException`? Then I will have to do it for `service2()`, `service3()` and so on.

Is it better to let the invoker (a servlet in my case) to do this?

What exactly should be wrapped in remote exception - everything that happens in the server? or only exceptions dealing with the remote invocation process (reflection, serialization, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shouldn't be throwing `RemoteException`, it should be reserved for the WS framework if and when errors occur accessing the remote service.

Most of the frameworks will catch `Exception`, wrap it up as a SOAP-Fault, which is the client deals with normally by throwing another exception with the error message from the SOAP-Fault (remember the client may not be Java).

The up-shot of this is you should throw exceptions specific to the fault that has occurred, leaving the framework to send the appropriate response.

Comment: Wow, I somehow missed your answer until now. Sounds as if I've been doing it all wrong...
Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you only need to declare that the methods throw `RemoteException` in the interface.

```
public interface MyService extends Remote {
  public void service1() throws RemoteException;
}
```