# Remove repetitive try/catch code

Tags: java, web-services, methods, try-catch

I have the following code in many methods

```
try{ user = userList.get(user_id); }
catch(Exception e) { return "USER_NOT_FOUND"; }
```

I find my self using the code quite a lot in different METHODS, to remove the repedidnes I could try create a method like this: (EXAMPLE)

```
.. returnUser(){

    try{ return user = userList.get(user_id); }
    catch(Exception e) { return "USER_NOT_FOUND"; }
}
```

This however would only return a user or a String and not brake out of the medthod if user was not found: (NOT WORKING)

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.pring("This will run always");
    User a = returnUser();
    System.out.pring("this should only run if a user was returned");
    System.out.pring("otherwise 'USER_NOT_FOUND' should be returned and end app.");
    ....
    ....
    return "Succsess";
 }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can you just return a brake out of the method and return the string and end the iditial method?

**Code example:**

```
public String completeTodo(){

    Todo todo; // Instantiate User object
    User user; // Instantiate todo object

    try{ todo = todoList.get(user_id); } //repeditive in all functions
    catch(Exception e) { return "TODO_NOT_FOUND"; }

    try{ user = userList.get(user_id); } //repeditive in some functions
    catch(Exception e) { return "USER_NOT_FOUND"; }

    if(user.getToken() == token){

                 user.setDef(1);
                 return user.toString();    

    }

    return "USER_NOT_VALID";

}
```

Comment: How about you show us your real code and your real approaches? None of that code looks even slightly correct and I rather doubt that any of it actually compiled. You can't return a User *or* a String in Java. Unless you used returntype Object, which I really hope you didn't.

Comment: Does `userList.get` method throws any exception?

Comment: @G.S no, but it could.

Comment: If you want your code to throw an exception, why catch it?
Or change your methods to return (and expect) false in these cases.

Comment: @CezarisLT then on which method you are catching the exception? Your `catch` block executes only if any exception has been thrown.

Comment: It looks like you are catching that exception too early: just let it bubble up the stack until you can appropriately handle it.

Comment: @G.S that why its an example, i dont know how to write it. I want return to not execute the rest of the code as illustrated in last example. I dont know how to do this.

Comment: @assylias Please check out my last example and how it should work, the try cahch code is an example.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig Please check out my new Code example, maybe it will make more sence

Comment: I think you should listen to @assylias. You catch the exceptions too early. There is no need to use a try-catch-block here. Just let the method throw an Exception if something went wrong and then the caller of the method can figure out what to do about that. Besides...using strings like `USER_NOT_FOUND` is a fairly bad way to handle an error. And why do you return only the user's string represenation instead of the actual object? What if you need another property of the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function that returns a user

```
public User returnUser() throws UserNotFoundException {

    try{
         return user = userList.get(user_id);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException ("user " + user + " not found");
    }
}
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String... args){

    try {
        System.out.println ("This will run always");

 // this will not work because returnUser() is not a static method and there is no "this" in "static void main()"
        User user = this.returnUser();

        System.out.println ("this should only run if a user was returned");
        return "Success";

    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.pring("otherwise 'USER_NOT_FOUND' should be returned and end app.");
    }
```

Exception classes

```
class AppException extends Exception {
    public AppException(String msg) {
         super(msg);
    }
}

class UserNotFoundException extends AppException {
    public UserNotFoundException(String msg) {
         super(msg);
    }
}
```

**UPD**

Here is what I mean with data service, the code is compilable

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        App app = new App();

        try {
            app.run();

        } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("'USER_NOT_FOUND'");
        } catch (TodoNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("'TODO_NOT_FOUND'");
        } catch (AppException e) {
            System.out.println("Some other application exception");
        }
    }

    DataService dataService = null;

    public void run() throws AppException {

        System.out.println("This will run always");

        prepareDataService();

        completeTodo(1, 2);

        System.out.println("this should only run if a user was returned");

    }

    void prepareDataService() {

        List<Todo> todoList = new ArrayList<Todo>();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

        dataService = new DataService(todoList, userList);
    }

    void completeTodo(int todoId, int userId) throws AppException {

        Todo todo = dataService.findTodo(todoId);
        User user = dataService.findUser(userId);

        user.doSomething(todo);
    }
}

class DataService {

    private List<Todo> todoList;
    private List<User> userList;

    public DataService(List<Todo> todoList, List<User> userList) {
        this.todoList = todoList;
        this.userList = userList;
    }

    public Todo findTodo(int todoId) throws TodoNotFoundException {
        Todo todo = null;

        // find todo here

        if (todo == null) {
            throw new TodoNotFoundException("todo " + todo + " not found");
        }
        return todo;
    }

    public User findUser(int userId) throws UserNotFoundException {
        User user = null;

        // find user here

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("user " + user + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }
}

class Todo {
}

class User {

    public void doSomething(Todo todo) {
    };
}

class AppException extends Exception {
    public AppException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

class TodoNotFoundException extends AppException {
    public TodoNotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}

class UserNotFoundException extends AppException {
    public UserNotFoundException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check out my new Code example, maybe it will make more sence

Comment: Perhaps, you will want all your find() methods be in a separate class(es), this will be like DAO pattern (google it). Then you will ask for user as userService.get(id) and it could throw an exception.

Comment: Can you update your code to this and ill will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your todo method like this:

```
public String completeTodo() throws SpecificExceptionHere {
    Todo todo = todoList.get(user_id);
    User user = userList.get(user_id);
    if (user.getToken() == token){
        user.setDef(1);
        return user.toString();    
    } else {
        throw new AppropriateException("Invalid token: " + user.getToken());
    }
}
```

And leave the exception handling to the calling code.

Comment: The problem THAT IS the executed code, I'm using Web Services. completeTodo will be called by the framework and I have no controll of that? What should i do.

Comment: I missed that important detail.

Comment: @CezarisLT This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322222/best-practice-for-java-web-services-and-remote-exception